# Serializing JSON array of 2 doubles to strongly typed object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm using Newtonsoft.JSON and I have a JSON array where each array member is itself an array of two numbers, e.g.

```
{
    "objList": [
        [8.8, 4],
        [9.2, 1.45],
        [1.61, 32.79]
    ]
}
```

I want to deserialize this into a class MyObjList defined by

```
public class MyObjList {
    [DataMember(Name = "objList")]
    public List<MyObj> ObjList { get; set; }
}
```

where MyObj is the class

```
public class MyObj {
    public double FirstDouble{ get; set; }
    public double SecondDouble { get; set; }
}
```

I knew that more work was required, but just tying the above gave me a helpful error message that told me that I could put `[JsonArrayAttribute]` on the MyObj class, i.e.

```
[JsonArrayAttribute]
public class MyObj{
    public double FirstDouble{ get; set; }
    public double SecondDouble { get; set; }
}
```

That has moved things on and the deserializer now fails at the next stage where it's looking for a suitable constructor.  But I don't know how to write the constructor that is required and I can't find any examples.  Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Your question is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34047955/10263).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're keen on using `MyObj` instead of `List<double>`, you could try by creating a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconverter.htm) for your `MyObj` type — *which basically just wraps the whole `List<double>` deserialization and feeding it to the `MyObj` type* — like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyObjConverter))]
public class MyObj{
  public double FirstDouble{ get; set; }
  public double SecondDouble { get; set; }
}

public class MyObjConverter : JsonConverter
{
  public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
    return objectType == typeof(MyObj);     
  }

  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {                
    var doubles = serializer.Deserialize<List<double>>(reader);
    return new MyObj { FirstDouble = doubles[0], SecondDouble = doubles[1] };                       
  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

---

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x0FCFX

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for :-).  FYI, I was able to make the JsonArrayAttribute method work, but only by implementing the IList interface on the class MyObj which was far from ideal!

Answer (score 1):

The `JSON` you have, does not represent you object `MyObjList`.

```
{
    "objList": [
        [8.8, 4],
        [9.2, 1.45],
        [1.61, 32.79]
    ]
}
```

Your `JSON` is basically a `List<List<double>>`.

One easy way to create your object out of this data, is to use `Linq-to-JSON` from `Json.NET` and construct your object like this

```
var jsonString = @"{ ""objList"": [ [8.8, 4], [9.2, 1.45], [1.61, 32.79] ] }";
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

var myObjList = new MyObjList
{
    ObjList = jObject["objList"]
                .ToObject<List<List<double>>>()
                .Select(list => new MyObj { FirstDouble = list[0], SecondDouble = list[1] })
                .ToList()
};
```

See the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) for more details.

Comment: Your answer suggests that all I need to do is to put a constructor `public MyObj(List<double> list){}` onto my object.  If that's right, presumably I would need to decorate that constructor somehow?

Comment: There should be a way to do that, but I'm not sure what `Attribute` to use. You might need to write some custom `JsonConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is a requirement mapping your doubles into a actual class like that. I think doing that would only complicate things. This is the simplest way to get it working:

**MyObjList**

```
public class MyObjList
{
   public List<List<double>> objList { get; set; }
}
```

And in a POST you will get this:

[image: POST]

Comment: Thanks, and yes indeed, I have it working like that.  I'm just looking for a more readable method :-)